# How are random forests used to estimate missing data? Literature on the area?

Tags: matrices, statistics, machine-learning, parameter-estimation, data-analysis

I am exploring imputation techniques to deal with my missing data and I have come across using a random Forest to deal with these values. Does anybody have any literature behind how this could be applied to data imputation?

Comment: Why do you think this could work? RandomForests is a supervised learning method. Imputing missing data is basically an unsupervised problem. That said, RandomForest doesn't really have a big problem with missing data.

Comment: This question might be better posted on the statistics stack exchange site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/